# À quand remonte l'apparition de l'expression « un bain de foule » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, étymologie

Baudelaire écrivait :

> Il n'est pas donné à chacun de prendre un bain de multitude : jouir de la foule est un art ; et celui-là seul peut faire, aux dépens du genre humain, une ribote de vitalité, à qui une fée a insufflé dans son berceau le goût du travestissement et du masque, la haine du domicile et la passion du voyage.

Il n'est pourtant pas évident de trouver des traces de l'expression « un bain de foule » qui soient antérieures et revêtues du sens qu'on lui connait aujourd'hui (*foule* pouvant aussi désigner à l'époque l'action que l'on désignerait *foulage* de nos jours, soit l'action de *fouler*).
Le caractère idiomatique et l'adoption de cette expression [semblent](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+bain+de+foule%2C+un+bain+de+multitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) relativement récents.

Quand est-elle véritablement apparue ? Baudelaire y faisait-il déjà référence ?

L'origine et la chronologie des [multiples sens](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/foule) du mot *foule* constitueraient-elles un début de réponse ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Baudelaire ne connaissait probablement pas l'expression « bain de foule » telle que nous l'employons aujourd'hui dans son sens métaphorique.
Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue Française* (sld alain Rey) donne 1960 pour l'apparition de l'expression *bain de foule*, le mot **foule** étant employé dans son sens le plus commun aujourd'hui : un grand nombre de personnes. 
C'est confirmé si on regarde le [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20bain%20de%20foule&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) : le pic de 1960 correspond à l'apparition de cet emploi, les occurrences datant d'avant 1960 correspondent à l'emploi premier non métaphorique : le bain (le liquide) dans lequel était trempé le tissu qui était foulé. La foule désignant l'action de fouler, on dit plutôt foulage de nos jours.

Le substantif *foule* dérive du verbe *fouler*, du latin *fullare* « fouler une étoffe ».
Le verbe a gardé un sens technique de « presser en appuyant » (fouler du drap, fouler, le raisin, etc.). *Foulage* s'est au fil des siècles substitué à *foule* pour désigne l'action de fouler dans les domaines techniques (le drap, le feutre...).

Alain Rey *& al* datent l'apparition de *foule* au sens d'« une multitude de personnes » de 1172. La foule, c'est l'endroit ou se presse (ou où sont pressés) une multitude de personnes.
L'usage du mot pour désigner la majorité de la masse humaine (en opposition à l'élite) date de 1670.